# How to perform an e2e test of the Google Pay (Adyen) flow with Codeceptjs?

Tags: e2e-testing, applepay, google-pay, codeceptjs, adyen

I am trying to perform an e2e test using Codeceptjs (with Puppeteer) for the Google Pay payment gateway implemented using Adyen. Currently I can get to select the radio button but I cannot automatically switch to the iframe or pop-up window that should come out and enter the relevant google account there to make the payment by selecting one of the test cards that it allows.
[Environment / web browser snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIpaC.png)

Is it possible to do this? I have not found any example of WebDriver or other tool that does something similar for Google Pay or Apple Pay

Answer (score 0):

This isn't currently possible at the moment (Google Pay and Chrome). On Chrome, I believe it has a dependency on the following issue: https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=927783

One thing you can do to help make the issue more visible is to **star** the issue.

The only thing I can suggest for now is to provide an alternate behavior for the button and invoke the next step in your application with a stubbed out response.